# Resharper 5 Beta - Goto Declaration (CTRL + Click) is not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper, shortcut

In Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 with Resharper 5 Beta, Goto Declaration (CTRL + Click) is not working. Anybody has solution for that? I tried in google but couldn't find any solution yet.

Comment: I have this problem also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737912/go-to-declaration-does-not-work-in-resharper-on-vs2005-2008-2010-2012-on-win8-64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try the (free) extension I wrote that makes ctrl+click invoke Go To Definition: [Go To Definition (on the VS Gallery)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/4b286b9c-4dd5-416b-b143-e31d36dc622b), or download it from inside Visual Studio 2010 by going to the Extension Manager and searching for it by name (or for my name).

Comment: Finally unistalled resharper now and using this extension now.  i am hoping that we will get more and more extesnion of what resharper provides now so that we wont depends on third party softwares.

Comment: If you find bugs, you can report them on my blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/noahric) or on the github page (http://github.com/noahric/gotodef) for this extension.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737912/go-to-declaration-does-not-work-in-resharper-on-vs2005-2008-2010-2012-on-win8-64

Answer (score 1):

Its a beta it was broken. They have updated and fixed it now.

if you want to get the Daily Build it is avalible at
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+7+EAP

Although I'm sure that link will stop working when R#7 goes gold.

Comment: Where can I get the `nightly builds`? Do they have a public repository?

Comment: i tried the night build too.. it didnt work.. and i dont find anybody reported this in their bug reporting tool..

Comment: @ Mendy : Nightly build are here.
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+5.0+Nightly+Builds

Comment: @ Jeeva : 
Do you have any other addons, which could conflict ?
Go to Resharper > Options... > Search & Navigation and make sure the 3 option is ticked.
Or finally highlight a usage of a varible, Go to Resharper > Go to > 
 Declaration and does that work ?

Comment: No. It doesnt.. and i checked 3rs option is ticked.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought it wasn't working either, but then I realized that it just works differently (not as good IMO):

If you quickly go CTRL-Click, nothing happens.  But if you hold down CTRL, until a blue underline appears, and THEN click, it goes to the definition (for me anyway).