# Do resharper 5 beta stop working?

Tags: resharper, resharper-5.0

I got message that the license expired to resharper 5 beta. I waited a few days but nothing was updated.

Is anyone else got this message?

In addition [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207639/resharper-5-beta-goto-declaration-ctrl-click-is-not-working/2207813#2207813) post says that there is nightly builds. 
The question how can I get them.
I there a public repository that I can get any update to this program?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the nightly builds here:

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+5.0+Nightly+Builds

On license it says:

> You can install a ReSharper 5 nightly
>   build and evaluate it for 30 days,
>   irrelevant of whether you have a
>   ReSharper license or not (except for
>   some ReSharper 4.5 users who qualify
>   for a free upgrade - see below.) If
>   your nightly build expires before
>   ReSharper 5 is released, you can
>   download and install a fresh nightly
>   build and continue evaluation.
>   However, if you have purchased or
>   upgraded to ReSharper 4.5 on October
>   15, 2009 or later, you qualify for a
>   free upgrade to ReSharper 5.0. You can
>   use ReSharper 5 Beta, ReSharper 5
>   nightly builds, and ReSharper 5
>   release build without any
>   restrictions.