# Go to declaration does not work in resharper on vs2005/2008/2010/2012 on win8 64 bit?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit, resharper

I have a `User` class which I created.

However when i <kbd>CTRL+left mouse click</kbd> on it's *instances* , it *suppose* to go to the class "`User`" itself :

[image]

**But it doesn't.** ( it should. in vs2010 it works).

But if I right click on it and choose : "goto declaration"

[image]

It does work : and redirects me to : (the `User` Class)

[image]

resharper  ver : 7.1.3000.2254
vs 2012 pro

Here are the current settings :

[image]

- How can I fix it ?

## Edit.

After another check, it's also with vs2010.
I guess the problem is compatibility with win8 64bit.
(I have no addons installed. and did try reset settings etc.).

## edit 2

I dont know if it's helping but when I pres ctrl and mouse over the class it does underline it :

[image]

and when I press click ( with ctrl) - it opens the surround with tool tip :

[image]

Comment: Oh SHI*.  I think there is no solution. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditor/thread/45bf6dbe-0910-4692-ab18-d4da51d42d60#07a82495-c6b0-4466-907a-6a49dc4d5c40

Comment: @charles , please next time dont delete tags just like that. it might be a problem only in 64. or not. the question is regarding(for me) to windows 8 64bit. hence the tag.

Comment: The only clue that you're using Windows 8, or that you think it might be a 64-bit issue is in that tag.  Perhaps if you really think it's an issue, you should add that information to the question.  Further, we *already* have a tag for Windows 8, and *already* have a tag for 64-bit things.  If you insist on believing that this is a Windows 8 issue, or an issue unique to 64-bit architectures, you should use appropriate tags for that and update your question body.

Comment: @Charles well , thats a very different thing. (in contrast to delete the tag entirly). ill update.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - mind sharing your VS text - editor color scheme ?

Comment: @AppDeveloper Sure. you'd love it. I gaurantee. http://www.filedropper.com/exported-2013-05-26 ( sharp fonts , highlight really the important things , etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check that you also have the following setting turned on:

[image]

With this setting turned off, click navigation doesn't work.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I've just checked my settings and I have the "Navigation to sources" option checked as well. Have you tried that?

Comment: please look at the pic. it is only one selection. it cant select both.

Comment: That's what I meant - select "Navigation to sources" (in your third picture).

Comment: @RoyiNamir If you're sure that you've turned on "Go to Declaration on <Control + Left Click> in editor" and it doesn't work, then you should contact ReSharper's support, see http://www.jetbrains.com/support/resharper/

Comment: @DmitryOsinovskiy p.s. it's also with vs 2010. I guess its becuase windows8-64bit I have....(is there special edition resharper for 64bit ? )

Comment: @RoyiNamir No, we have one ReSharper for all Windows editions. I have Windows 8 64bit, and Ctrl+Left click works for me.

Answer (score 0):

We've been fixing some of the Ctrl+Click related issues in the R# v8 line — possibly this case is already there.

Could you try an [early preview build for v8](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+8+EAP)?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the OP's situation, but i'm using VS on Win8 running in VMWare on a Mac.
VMWare by default, seems to enable ctrl+left mouse click as a right click.

So holding control and hovering was underlining the object as the OP says, but clicking would bring up the right click menu in windows.

[Disabling the ctrl+click shortcut](http://blogs.vmware.com/teamfusion/2008/11/tip-control-cli.html) in VMWare fixed it for me